# Java's LinkedList vs. Scala's DoubleLinkedList

Tags: scala, linked-list, queue, fifo, doubly-linked-list

In a Scala project, I need a simple, mutable queue data structure where I can append items on one end and take out items on the other (i.e. FIFO). Now, I'm not sure whether I should use the plain old `LinkedList` from Java, or Scala's `DoubleLinkedList`. What are the relative advantages of these two? Should I always prefer the `DoubleLinkedList`, or is there any good reason to use `LinkedList`? Also, are there any other options worth considering?

Comment: Java linked list doesn't have scala's glorified collection api, in other aspects, I think they will be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for other options, consider using a [scala.collection.mutable.Queue](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Queue).
There is even an immutable version: [scala.collection.immutable.Queue](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Queue).

A quote from the doc:

> Queue objects implement data structures that allow to insert and retrieve elements in a first-in-first-out (FIFO) manner.

so if your intention is to have a FIFO/Queue, the class name `Queue` could be easier to read/maintain than any `LinkedList`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interface with Java code it is perhaps an advantage to use the `LinkedList`.

Else if you only have scala code then go for the `DoubleLinkedList` as it has many advantages in scala.